# Positioning vertical center

Tags: html, css, position, scale, center

I want to center these 4 images. Horizontally it is working but vertically it won't work. Does anybody knows how to solve this problem? At the moment I've got a black header/footer section with 4 images centered horizontally. Everything is scalable but not the height of the images.

Am doing it right?

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
section {
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    bottom:5%;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
}
section img {
    width:12.5%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```

Comment: Does the section element need to have a height of 90%?

Comment: @j08691 I assume it's because the header/footer has a totaled height of 10%

Comment: yeah, header and footer 5 % so section 90%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its easier to wrap the images in a container and then center the container in the container's parent, in this case you could use an Article tag to wrap the images an then center that article in the section like this

HTML

```
<section>
    <article>
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
        </div>
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
        </div>
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
        </div>
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="img.png" alt="Pic" />
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

section {
    top: 5%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;

    /* strech */
    overflow: hidden;
}

article {
    width:80%;
    height:40%; /* change this to set height */

    /* CSS absolute center begin */
    border: 2px solid #0000ff;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;

    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    /* CSS absolute center end*/
}

.pic {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.pic img{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Hope it help you

Comment: It works, thanks man. need to adjust the stretch, but okay. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the width of the image equals the height of the image (like the code you gave has), you can just use `margin-top` of `50% - imageHeight`. That would look like

```
section img {
    width:12.5%;
    margin-top:32.5%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwC2m/)

If they're not, you can use [this pure CSS approach](http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gEiDt)

Comment: Sorry but the height's of the images aren't the same as the width's

Comment: @user2438434 Added an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can give the section `position:relative;` and then do a trick with the images.

The sample below makes them centered of the section, if you want to have the images spread out, but vertically aligned, you need to do this trick on  the containing element (like a dive around the images in the section:

```
section {
    position:relative;
    top:5%;
    bottom:5%;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
}
section img {
    /*width:12.5%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;*/
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-25%;/* should be half the height of the image */
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25%;/* should be half the width of the image */
}
```

Comment: You cannot have both `top` and `bottom` values, only the `bottom` value is being used. Also this will position all four images in the same location, not with space in between

Comment: @ZachSaucier correct, I forgot to clean the OP's code. And yes this an vertical and horizontal centered example as indicated in the answer. To space in between you need to add an element.Your answer is generally better hence I upvoted it ;-)